# Custom ValidatorFn - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to create a custom generic validator, which will pass by parameter the pattern of the regular expression and the name of the property (of a formgroup) to be checked. I have the following code

```
UserName: new FormControl('',
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        this.OnlyNumbersAndLetterValidator(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "UserName")
      ]
    )

OnlyNumbersAndLetterValidator(regexPattern: RegExp, propertyName: string): ValidatorFn {
        return (currentControl: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
          if (!regexPattern.test(currentControl.value)) {
            return { propertyName: true }
          }
        }
      }
```

The problem is that when the expression is not valid, return **"{propertyName: true}"**, instead of **"{UserName: true}"**, what is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a temp object and then return. Here `propertyName` in `return { propertyName: true }` is a string and not the input variable.

```
OnlyNumbersAndLetterValidator(regexPattern: RegExp, propertyName: string): ValidatorFn {
        return (currentControl: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
          if (!regexPattern.test(currentControl.value)) {
           let temp = {};
           temp[propertyName] = true;
            return temp;
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `{ propertyName: true }` which means an object with a property named `propertyName`

What you want to do is:

```
let returnValue = {};
returnValue[propertyName] = true;
return returnValue;
```

Or even shorter:

```
return { [propertyName]: true };
```